# ProGuard causing error in MoPub Integration - AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, mopub

I added this in my build.gradle(mopub-sdk) file

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true;
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), file('proguard.txt')
        }
 }
```

My proguard.txt file is

```
# Keep public classes and methods.
-keepclassmembers class com.mopub.** { public *; }
-keep public class com.mopub.**
-keep class com.mopub.mobileads.**{*;}
-keep public class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial
-keep public class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
-keep public class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface {}

# Keep interfaces
-keep interface com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial.InterstitialAdListener
-keep interface com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.BannerAdListener


# Explicitly keep any custom event classes in any package.
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBanner {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventInterstitial {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.nativeads.CustomEventNative {}

# Support for Android Advertiser ID.
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info {*;}
```

But upon building, I get this error:

```
Error:(33, 45) error: cannot find symbol class InterstitialAdListener
Error:(35, 37) error: cannot find symbol class BannerAdListener
```

and a couple of others but most of them are related to the above two. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Faced same issue.Check my answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am going to try it. But minifyEnabled true or false? I want proguard to obfuscate the mopub sdk files too

Comment: I am getting an error:  Gradle DSL method not found: 'minifyEnabled()'
Possible causes:The project 'xxxxx' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file. The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: MY gradle plugin version is 0.13

Comment: Please check my updated answer . If not working let me inform .

Comment: hi ok..i'll try and will post the response.

Comment: hi, i got the following error:                                          Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 1 sec
6:20:40 PM UnsupportedMethodException
           Failed to set up Android modules in project 'xxxxx': Unsupported method: SourceProvider.getJniDirectories().
           The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
           To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
           Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.

Comment: Update classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+' this . Your logic true . .14+ not supported

Comment: hi thanks..from another post, the problem seems i need to update android studio to latest version.  i 'll come back after that..pls keep in touch

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 0.14.0 or higher of the `gradle` plugin, you should replace "`runProguard`" with "`minifyEnabled`" in your **build.gradle** files.

**`minifyEnabled`** false Means Build Type names cannot be main or androidTest (this is enforced by the plugin), and that they have to be unique to each other.

Just Update this :

```
 buildTypes {           
     release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                }
            }
```

And update your **classpath**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+'
```

Comment: hi, even after updating studio and sdk, and changing runProguard to minifyEnabled, the error still remains the same